# Counting number of words inside a text file and printing results in a different text file in c/c++

Tags: c, file, count

the code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char filename[] = "11.txt";
char filename1[] = "2.txt";
FILE *ptr, *resultptr;
char string[100];
char words[100][100];
int len = sizeof(filename) / sizeof(char);
int i = 0, j = 0, k, length, count;

int main()
{
    fopen_s(&ptr, filename, "r");
    fopen_s(&resultptr, filename1, "w");

    if ((ptr == nullptr) || (resultptr == nullptr)) {
        printf("Files were not opened!");
        return -1;
    }
    while (fgets(string, sizeof string, ptr)) {
        for (k = 0; string[k] != '\0'; k++) {
            if (string[k] != ' ' && string[k] != '\n') {
                words[i][j++] = tolower(string[k]);
            } else {
                words[i][j] = '\0';
                i++;
                j = 0;
            }
        }
        length = i + !!j;
        fputs("Occurrences of each word:\n", resultptr); //prints this sentence into file
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (strcmp(words[i], "0") == 0)
                continue;
            count = 1; 
            char *ch = words[i];
            for (j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
                if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) == 0 && (strcmp(words[j], "0") != 0))         {
                    count++;
                    strcpy_s(words[j], "0");
                }   
            }
            fputs("The word ", resultptr);
            if (string[i] != ' ' && string[i] != '\n') {
                fprintf(resultptr, "%s", ch);
            }
            fputs(" occurred ", resultptr);
            fprintf(resultptr, "%d", count);
            fputs(" times\n", resultptr);
        }
        fclose(ptr);
        fclose(resultptr);
        return 0;
     }
 }
```

The counting part is working perfectly fine, but the problem is when I try to print results, for the sentence "to be or not: to be that is the question ..." it prints this:

```
Occurrences of each word:
The word to occurred 2 times
The word be occurred 2 times
The word  occurred 1 times
The word not: occurred 1 times
The word that occurred 1 times
The word is occurred 1 times
The word  occurred 1 times
Occurrences of each word:
The word to occurred 1 times
The word be occurred 1 times
The word or occurred 1 times
The word  occurred 1 times
The word that occurred 1 times
The word is occurred 1 times
The word  occurred 2 times
The word question occurred 1 times
The word ... occurred 1 times
```

What's messing? like I'm not professional, but can someone guide me on what's wrong here? I changed a bit from the original one but still a lot of mistakes

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232821/discussion-on-question-by-youngwildandfree-counting-numbers).

Comment: Please don't change the question in such a way that it invalidates the existing answers. I have rolled back your recent edits. If you want to update your question with a follow-up question, then you can add it to the bottom of the question. As long as the original question is left intact, this will not invalidate the existing answers.

Comment: @Youngwildandfree: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- the global variables should be moved inside the body of the `main()` function.
- `fopen_s()` is not portable, use `fopen()` instead.
- `strcpy_s()` is not portable, use `strcpy()` instead or just set the first byte if the string to `'\0'` to make it an empty string.
- `i` and `j` should be reset to `0` after each `fgets()`.
- you should test for letters with `isalpha()` instead of only testing for space and newline.
- you should clear the duplicated words by setting them to the empty string.
- you should use a simple `fprintf()` call for the output line.
- you should not close the files inside the `while(fgets(...))` loop.

If you want to count all words in the file, this approach is limited to a rather small number of words. A more general solution would construct a dictionary of words found as you read the file contents and increment the count for each word found.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning(disable:4996)  // disable Microsoft obnoxious warning
#endif

#define WORDS 2000
#define CHARS 40

int main() {
    char filename[] = "11.txt";
    char filename1[] = "2.txt";
    FILE *ptr, *resultptr;
    char string[100];
    char words[WORDS][CHARS];
    int i, j, k, length, count;

    ptr = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    resultptr = fopen(filename1, "w");
    if (resultptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", filename1, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    i = j = 0;

    while (i < WORDS && fgets(string, sizeof string, ptr)) {
        for (k = 0; string[k] != '\0'; k++) {
            unsigned char c = string[k];
            if (isalpha(c)) {
                if (j < CHARS - 1)
                    words[i][j++] = tolower(c);
            } else {
                words[i][j] = '\0';
                if (j > 0) {
                    j = 0;
                    i++;
                    if (i == WORDS)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (j > 0) {
            // include the last word if the file does not end with a newline
            words[i][j] = '\0';
            i++;
        }
    }
    length = i;
    fprintf(resultptr, "Occurrences of each word:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (words[i][0] == '\0')
            continue;
        count = 1; 
        for (j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
            if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) == 0)         {
                count++;
                words[j][0] = '\0';
            }   
        }
        fprintf(resultptr, "The word %s occurred %d times\n", words[i], count);
    }
    fclose(ptr);
    fclose(resultptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note: Meanwhile, OP has applied the mentioned fixes to the question, thereby invalidating this answer. This answer applies to [revision 4 of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67644828/4).**

> What's messing?

1. `The word 0 occurred 1 times` - You chose to replace word duplicates with the string `"0"`. In order to not count those replacements as words, insert

   ```
               if (strcmp(words[i], "0") == 0) continue;
   ```

   at the very beginning of the printing `for` loop body. It seems you intended `if (string[i] != ' ' && string[i] != '\0' && string[i]!='0' )` to do this, but that doesn't work - remove this code.
   Besides, the empty string would be a better choice, allowing the word `0`.
2. `The word` 
    `occurred 1 times` - The `'\n'` at the end was counted as a word. In order to not count this and in addition skip punctuation as well as avoid empty words due to consecutive non-word characters, replace

   ```
               if (string[k] != ' ' && string[k] != '\0') {
                   words[i][j++] = tolower(string[k]);
               }
               else
   ```

   with

   ```
               if (isalnum(string[k]))
                   words[i][j++] = tolower(string[k]);
               else if (j)
   ```
3. `The word  occurred 1 times` - An empty word at the end of file was counted. In order to not count that, add 1 to i only if inside a word at EOF, i. e. change

   ```
           length = i + 1;
   ```

   to

   ```
           length = i + !!j;
   ```

Comment: That's because you call `fgets` only once. To change this, replace `fgets(string, 100, ptr); //reads a line

    while (!feof(ptr)) {` with `while (fgets(string, sizeof string, ptr))` and remove the then surplus `}` at the end.

Comment: If it prints _The word 0_, it seems you haven't made the change 1. above.

Comment: And since one can't format data in comments properly, you'd better insert the true content of the input file into the question post between lines ```.

Comment: Put it after `for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {`. - I'm off now and will be back in two hours, looking after other issues - if you haven't fixed them yourself by then. ;-)

Comment: As how many words shall for example _built-in_ be counted?

Comment: I added another needed change to 1. above, which I overlooked before.

Comment: Regarding punctuation, `ispunct` is a good approach - probably you didn't implement it properly.

Comment: Anyway, I expanded 2. above to handle punctuation etc.

Comment: I think the reason is that you didn't apply my changes correctly, especially the one in my first **comment**.

Comment: I'm not convinced that you did. Perhaps you can show how you did.